# How to set a dynamic height value to a wave in svg based on % value?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I want to design dynamic wave effect with help of `svg`. Suppose I have passed value 40%, wave should appear 40%. Based on the value, wave effect should increase or decrease.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path fill="#FFF6E3" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L48,197.3C96,203,192,213,288,229.3C384,245,480,267,576,250.7C672,235,768,181,864,181.3C960,181,1056,235,1152,234.7C1248,235,1344,181,1392,154.7L1440,128L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z">
    </path>
</svg>
```

[image: You can refer this image based on 42% wave should appear]

[image]

Comment: "wave should appear 40%" doesn't mean anything. Also, what is your question and what did you try?

Comment: @geoffrey you can refer images ..then you will understand my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what is meant by 40% etc increase, using transform scale on the y but leaving the x will result in the waves being higher.

For example, to get them 5 times higher (than the heights of the SVG given in the question) use transform: `scale(1, 5)`

```css
svg {
  transform: scale(1, 5);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
     <path  fill="#FFF6E3" fill-opacity="1"        d="M0,192L48,197.3C96,203,192,213,288,229.3C384,245,480,267,576,250.7C672,235,768,181,864,181.3C960,181,1056,235,1152,234.7C1248,235,1344,181,1392,154.7L1440,128L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z" ></path></svg>
```